# c# OpenFileDialog Location Not Available

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I have a very simple C# code not sure what I am missing, I need to open OpenFileDialog and select file but when I open it by clicking of a button on Documents, Desktop and Downloads short cuts in windows 10 it says Location is not available, but when I go to any of these folders directly from C drive and users directory it works fine.

Here is my code

```
var FD = new OpenFileDialog();
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
      dir = "defaultdirectory";
}

FD.InitialDirectory = dir;
if (FD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;
    uploadFile(fileToOpen);
}
```

And here is the screeshot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mkPJ.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem with code, more like with Windows. The shortcut on the left is pointing to the location that doesn't exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when in general I click on those shortcuts it works, and this is not only with my PC, I checked on few other and same result

Comment: This could happen when the program runs with an oddball user account.  A rather special one, the SYSTEM account.  Normally only ever used by a service.  You forgot to tell us how it got started.  Pretty dangerous, you want to google "shatter attack" to learn what kind of damage the user can do.

Comment: @Creative which folder are you trying to open? And how did the current directory end up *inside* the `system32` folder? BTW the current directory can't *not* exist which means `if (!Directory.Exists(dir))` can't work.

Comment: @Creative as Hans said, it looks like you are trying to use an account that you should never, ever use. Desktop, Documents etc are *account specific* and part of the account's profile. The `system` account is a special account that doesn't have any need for such folders. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Creative did you try to bypass security perhaps by running the application as `SYSTEM`? Or used a Scheduled Task under SYSTEM with the working directory set to `system32\config`? Modify the `hosts` file perhaps? What were you trying to do? There are correct ways to do whatever it was.